# how to understand tcpdump particular field field

Tags: tcpdump

I have below two tcpdump, Want to know what are "syslog.info" and "local6.info" column meaning? and what are the representation of syslog.info and local6.info

```
06:56:07.533143 IP 10.10.40.10.52126 > 10.18.40.58.514: SYSLOG **syslog.info**, length: 189
06:56:07.669902 IP 10.10.40.15.37866 > 10.18.40.58.514: SYSLOG **local6.info**, length: 292
```

Answer (score 1):

`void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);` where priority is `facility | level`.  In the string version above facility `syslog` and `local6` corresponds to `LOG_SYSLOG` and `LOG_LOCAL6`, and `info` is the level which corresponds to `LOG_INFO`.  As for semantic:

> LOG_SYSLOG: messages generated internally by syslogd(8)
> LOG_USER (default): generic user-level messages
> LOG_INFO: informational message